# Unable to generate Go Ethereum Bindings using abigen

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, golang

Not sure what the heck is going on, but I'm unable to use `abigen` to generate Go Ethereum bindings any more, I get an error that says `EvalSymlinks: too many links`

```
solidity@pop-os:~/Documents/Code/RTrade/Mining-Stake/solidity$ abigen -abi TokenLockupV2.abi -bin TokenLockupV2.bin -out test.go -pkg Test
EvalSymlinks: too many links
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I'm just a dummy. The problem at hand was that I had configured my go development environment to have all my appropriate packages in the appropriate places by default, however before running `abigen` I declare my `$GOPATH` variable, which I believe was causing `abigen` to attempt to import my packages twice

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your gopath is correct

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Install `abigen`

```
go get -u github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/
make
make devtools
```

Compile abi

```
solc --abi MyContract.sol | awk '/JSON ABI/{x=1;next}x' > MyContract.abi
solc --bin MyContract.sol | awk '/Binary:/{x=1;next}x' > MyContract.bin
```

Compile abi to Go package

```
abigen --bin=MyContract.bin --abi=MyContract.abi --pkg=mycontract --out=MyContract.go
```